# STRIPPRIVATESYMBOLS : error : EC_FORMAT when building windows

Tags: windows, cordova, build

I'm trying to build a project for windows using cordova build windows --arch="x86" and I got this error

STRIPPRIVATESYMBOLS : error : EC_FORMAT [D:\my-project\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows.jsproj]

Everything is ok when I build Android version.
I'm using VS2015, node 4.3.1 and npm 5.0.4.
I also have VS2012 installed on my computer for other projects

Has anyone run into the same problem ? Please tell me if you need further information

Thank you